# Get Context in async task

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to setState in async task but I get the following error:

**_this3.setState is not a function. (In '_this3.setState({
    dataSource: responseJson.movies,
    isLoading: false
  })', '_this3.setState' is undefined)**

I searched in google and I found that the meaning of the error is that I dont have the context in the async task, how I can get this context correctly?

The code send a request while the loading is running when the request success I want to setState to stop the loading and read the request response.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, ListView, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dataSource: null,
      isLoading: true
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    getData();
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.isLoading) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <ActivityIndicator size="large" />
        </View>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          {/* { 
            this.state.loading &&
            <View style={styles.loading}>
              <ActivityIndicator size='large' />
            </View>
          } */}

          <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>

          <Button
            onPress={() => {
              this.getData();
              this.state.loading = true;
            }}
            title="Get data"
            color="#841584"
            accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this purple button"
          />

        <ListView
          style={styles.container}
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          renderRow={(data) => <View><Text>{data}</Text></View>}
        />

        </View>
      );
    }
  }

  getData = () => {
    getMoviesFromApiAsync();
  }

  getMoviesFromApiAsync = () => {
    return fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        this.setState({
          dataSource: responseJson.movies,
          isLoading: false
        });
        console.log("end");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },

  loading: {
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
});
```

Comment: Is the `getMoviesFromApiAsync` function a method of the class, or is it defined outside of the component? If it's defined outside the component, you can't use `this.setState`.

Comment: @Tholle I modified the code adding the functions in the component but how I can access them now? I can't access getData using this.getData(). Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Register your function in constructor like this:
this.getDate = this.getDate.bind(this);
this.getMoviesFromApiAsync = this.getMoviesFromApiAsync.bind(this);

and then you will have access to setState

Answer (score 0):

In JS you define methods inside a class like this:

```
class Test {

  myfunction() {
    // do something
  }
}
```

This will allow you to call `this.myfunction()`.

So edit your code from `getData = () => {...}` to `getData() {...}` and you should be fine calling `this.getData()` inside your App component.